# Graph API returns empty data set for App Insight Data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to get App Insights like Post Impressions, Clicks etc from my FB App Insight using Graph API and FQL but not getting any data. There response has a Empty Data array.

Any pointers on this?

Also, what would be the FQL to get the number of impression for any story by an app.

Comment: What code are you using? do you have the correct permissions? was this working and stopped? if so ,when?

Comment: no..it never worked for me. Yeah I have correct permissions ( read_insights ) . Even I tried in the Graph API Explorer. Even Application Active User is not giving data

Comment: I Tried this fql/?q=SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=XXXX AND metric='application_active_users' AND period=period('day') AND end_time=end_time_date('2012-07-01')

Answer (score 0):

One thing I know, for some insights about a post of a Facebook fan page, a page needs at least 30 users(likes).

Then after one day your page insight data maybe showing up.

Comment: Is this still true?  And how do you know?  I'm getting empty data sets on page posts, but the group is a test group so nothing has more than a couple of Likes...

Comment: You have to have at least 30 likes and then wait for one day. Its written in Facebook documentation. I don't have the link readily available at this moment.